# Matrix inequality of inverses of sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality

$A$ and $B$ are two real symmetric non-singular matrices but not necessarily sign definite. Suppose $A+B$ is non-singular. I want to find a $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ such that $$(A+B)^{-1}\leq(A+\lambda I)^{-1}$$ where $A\leq B$ means $A-B$ is negative semi-definite. Does such $\lambda$ exist? How can I find it?

I have tried the identity $(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}(B^{-1}+A^{-1})^{-1}A^{-1}$. But it led me to

$$(A^{-1}+\lambda^{-1} I)^{-1}\leq(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by [Schur's complement identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).

It holds that the following three matrices are congruent.
$$\begin{bmatrix}(A+\lambda I)^{-1}&I\\I&A+B\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}A+B&I\\I&(A+\lambda I)^1-(A+B)^{-1}\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}(A+\lambda I)^{-1}&I\\I&B-\lambda I\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $n_-(A)$ denote the number of negative eigenvalues of $A$. Then, by [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), $(A+\lambda I)^1\geq(A+B)^{-1}$ iff
\begin{equation}n_-(A+B)=n_-(A+\lambda I)+n_-(B-\lambda I)\end{equation}
But such $\lambda$ does not always exist, as shown by the excellent counterexample by @Rammus. In that example, $n_-(A+B)=0$ but no $\lambda$ can simultaneously make $n_-(A+\lambda I)=0$ and $n_-(B-\lambda I)$.

Anyways, if such $\lambda$ exists, the identity above provides a way to find it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot always do that. Here's a counterexample. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & - \epsilon \end{pmatrix} \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} - \epsilon & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
(A + B)^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}I
$$
and
$$
(A + \lambda I)^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{1+\lambda} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\lambda - \epsilon} \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
(A + \lambda I)^{-1} - (A+ B)^{-1}  &= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\epsilon-1} + \frac{1}{1+\lambda} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\epsilon-1} + \frac{1}{\lambda-\epsilon} \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

But then this latter matrix is positive semidefinite iff its diagonal entries are both non-negative. One can then show that if $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ no such $\lambda$ exists such that they are both non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

For positive [Definite symmetric matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix) (2/3 down on that page) one has $M\geq N > 0$ iff $N^{-1}\geq M^{-1} >0$ which under your hypotheses translates to
$$ 0< (A+B)^{-1} \leq (A +\lambda I)^{-1}$$
iff
$$ A+B\geq A +\lambda I > 0$$
or $B\geq \lambda I$. So if $B$ has a non-trivial kernel then you need $\lambda \leq 0$ (and $A$ should be strictly positive for the above to make sense).